# Change default language of android in-app products

Tags: android, localization, google-play, in-app-billing

We are developing an Android application that uses in-app billing. We are currently supporting about 4 languages in the app.

We want to have the default language be German meaning that if a user whose language is currently unsupported installs the app, all the app's content will be shown in German (I know that English would probably be more ideal since more people speak it but that's the requirement right now).

Changing the app's default language to German is no problem (I just make all the strings values in the default values folder German).

However, when the user views the in-app products, the products are only delivered in English. We also provide the same localizations for the in-app products as for the app itself.

How can I force the in-app products to be delivered in German if the user's language is not one of the supported languages?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default language for in-app products is inherited from application's default language as it is defined in *Developer Console*.

Open your application in *Developer Console*, choose *Store Listing* and select the language you want to be default (e.g. German). Then press on *Manage translations* selector. Choose *Change default language* option and confirm selection. Once done, all your in-app products will inherit new default language.